# You can't operate on a closed Connection

Tags: java, exception, database-connection

```
java.sql.SQLException: You can't operate on a closed Connection!!!
at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.createStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:104)
```

I want to access the table repeatedly. I want to open and close the result set To get the required information from the table. But I am getting this error. In this code I am using the connectionpooling concept. Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: You'll have to show some of the code that causes this error.

Comment: This question needs some work. Please include the relevant portions of your code and explain clearly what your problems are.

Answer (score 0):

The information you posted is pretty clear. Your connection is closed.

Maybe you are not closing just the ResultSet, but instead close the entire connection?

Finally, ensure that the connection is open before you try to do anything with it. If it is not, get a new connection.